# Does using parentheses around return values provide any compiler-related benefits?

Tags: c#, .net

Was just watching a video of a rather great Microsoft instructor, [Mike Taulty](http://channel9.msdn.com/Niners/mtaulty).  In his videos he consistently surrounded his return values with parentheses, even single values:

```
return (null);
```

Is there some hidden benefit with IntelliSense, or maybe something with the compiler, that this provides?

Code below:

```
public ObservableCollection<MailViewModel> Emails
{
  get
  {  
    return (emails);
  }
  set
  {
    emails = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Style and consistency. For example sometimes he might want  `return x + 1 * y` but it looks more clear as `return (x * 5 + y)`

Comment: Voting to reopen because although trivial, the question is IMHO not opinion-based. "Is there some hidden benefit with IntelliSense/the compiler" is a question which can answered objectively, even if the answer is simply no.

Comment: @Jon - agree totally, this is not really opinion based at all. I've favorited this already waiting for a response from some of the framework experts. If there is some tangible benefit I'd like to use it myself.

Comment: @Jon Well it wasn't closed ;) But you've convinced me not to vote to close :) I doubt anything interesting will come up though.

Answer (score 7):

There is certainly no performance difference because both forms translate to the **same IL**. The runtime couldn't tell even if it wanted. You can use Reflector or ILdasm or [any other decompiler](https://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en#complete=1&hl=en&q=free%20.net%20decompiler) to look at the generated IL.

There is no **intellisense** benefit or detriment.

The **semantics** are also exactly identical.

I will not discuss whether it is better **style** or not because that discussion does not belong on Stack Overflow. It is also a matter of personal taste.

Answer (score 2):

There's no benefit wrt the code generated. You can verify this by looking at the IL generated. As for whether it improves readability or not, that is subjective.

Comment: How would one look at the generated IL?

Comment: @sab669 ILdasm, ILSpy or any of the similar tools.